# Lumen/Laravel get attribute when using select and with

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I've run into this issue a couple of times now and I can't seem to find a solution - I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

I am making a JSON API with Lumen, building up specific routes for specific use cases. To speed up load times, I only want to output the fields I will be using.

My model has a combination of fields, relations and attributes. **I am struggling to specify the attribute when limiting output**

For example:

A `task` has `time_records`. Each `time_record` has a `value` of `time`.

I want to output the task names, time record values plus an attribute of `totalTime` which I have set on the `task` like the below (this isn't the full code but hopefully it gets across the idea)

```
class Task extends Model {

    protected $appends = [
        'totalTime'
    ];

    public function timeRecords() {
        return $this->hasMany('TimeRecord');
    }

    public function getTotalTimeAttribute() {
        $total = $this->timeRecords()->map(function($time_record){
            return $time_record->value;
        });

        return array_sum($total);
    }
}
```

If I then do the following:

```
Task::get();
```

And output that, I get all the tasks with the `totalTime` attribute. However, as mentioned I want to only output some attributes:

```
Task::select('id', 'name')
    ->with([
        'timeRecord' => function($query){
            $query->select('id');
        }
    ])
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the attribute output with that. The value is there in the array, but is null.

Comment: You can't access `accessor` values within the query builder, only with collection methods.

Comment: Also, you can use the `sum()` collection method within your `getTotalTimeAttribute()` class method instead of the `array_sum()` function you are using.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this, you have to select the fields that the attribute accesses.

Because I was *only* returning the ID of the `time_record`, the attribute was unable to calculate the `total_time` as the `value` field *was not* available.

(Was only while writing this question out did I discover the answer... )

Answer (score 1):

You can get that using `with()` method without callback. Callback method provide you to filter results..

```
Task::select('id', 'name')
    ->with("timeRecords:id") // use comma for multiple columns
    ->get();
```